# How to hide an accordion tab on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I open an accordion tab with one click, and I want to close it with the second click.

This is the JS/jQuery I have so far:

```
var APP = window.APP = window.APP || {};

APP.accordion = (function () {
    var $accordionHeader = $('.accordion__header');
    var $accordionContent = $('.accordion__content');

    var showAccordionContent = function(e) {
        var $t = $(this);

        $accordionHeader.removeClass('accordion__header--active');
        $t.addClass('accordion__header--active');

        $accordionContent.removeClass('accordion__content--expanded');
        $t.next().addClass('accordion__content--expanded');

        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $t.offset().top - 60
        }, 500);

        e.preventDefault();
    };

    var bindEventsToUI = function () {
        $accordionHeader.on('click', showAccordionContent);
    };

    var init = function () {
        bindEventsToUI();
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

}());
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion__tab">
    <a href="#" class="accordion__header accordion__header--active">
        Setting alerts
        <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>
            {{!-- things --}}
        </p>
        <ul class="cf">
            <li>
                {{!-- more things --}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion__tab">
    <a href="#" class="accordion__header">
        Setting alerts
        <span class="accordion__arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>
            {{!-- things --}}
        </p>
        <ul class="cf">
            <li>
                {{!-- more things --}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Just check to see if that tab has the class `.accordion__content--expanded` attached. If it does, remove that class and `return`. Also, seems to me that one of your classes, either `active` or `expanded` should do the same thing, and you can get rid of one, IMO. Active should mean expanded

Comment: @RobScott both have different purposes. Expanded is for one element and active for another element. Check the html so you may see what I say.

Comment: I guess what is missing here is calling of init function?

Comment: @SamarthSinha actually no. Everything is working fine. All I'm trying to figure out is how to close the accordion tab when it's open.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, just some pseudos

```
var bindEventsToUI = function () {
    $accordionHeader.on('click', toggleAccordionContent);
};

var toggleAccordionContent = function (e) {
    var accordionIsOpen = $(this).classList.indexOf('accordion__header--active') >= 0; // may need to use another selector base on `this`

    return accordionIsOpen ? hideAccordionContent.call(this) : showAccordionContent.call(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this. Modified showAccordionContent method logic a bit.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

This change will now close already open accordion on clicking it. And once you click on inactive accordion-header that will open. There might be a condition where user closes all the accordion after this code change.

```
var showAccordionContent = function(e) {
                var $t = $(this);

                /*Modified block logic*/
                if($t.hasClass('accordion__header--active')){
                    $t.removeClass('accordion__header--active');
                    $t.next().removeClass('accordion__content--expanded');
                }else{
                    $accordionHeader.removeClass('accordion__header--active');
                    $accordionContent.removeClass('accordion__content--expanded');
                    $t.addClass('accordion__header--active');
                    $t.next().addClass('accordion__content--expanded');
                }


                $('html, body').animate({
                                            scrollTop: $t.offset().top - 60
                                        }, 500);

                e.preventDefault();
            };
```